# Javascript function must return false if a new value don't exists in a List

Tags: javascript

I'm new to programming and would like to ask for help as to why my program is not working. When I run the checkName(); It just always returns true even if the input username is not in the lists yet or even when it already exists.

Instructions:
I have to create a function that will check if the username given by the user already exists. It must then return a true or a false.

Thank you!

```
let registeredUsers =  ["Xian","Sam","Gel", "Ian"];

let checkName = function() {
let username = prompt('Please enter username.');
let isExisting = registeredUsers.includes(username, 0);

    if (isExisting = true) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

checkName();
```

Comment: You missed an `=` sign: `if (isExisting = true) --> if (isExisting == true)` (you can also `return isExisting` directly)

Comment: @DDomen you should post that as an answer so the question gets closed, and you'll earn reputation for it. Although I'd recommend always using the === operator in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Btw you can avoid that waste of `if/else` statements since `registeredUsers.includes(username)` already returns `true/false`

```js
let registeredUsers =  ["Xian","Sam","Gel", "Ian"];

let checkName = function() {
  let username = prompt('Please enter username.');
  return registeredUsers.includes(username);
}

console.log(checkName());
```

Comment: The only thing to add to this answer is the link to [.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) so you can learn more how to use this method.

Answer (score 0):

You missed an `=` sign. By doing `if (isExisting = true)` you are assigning to the variable the `true` value, and then the if check will happen. That is the same as:

```js
isExisting = true;
if (isExisting) { ... }
```

You should correct your code as follow:

```js
let registeredUsers =  ["Xian","Sam","Gel", "Ian"];

let checkName = function() {
  let username = prompt('Please enter username.');
  let isExisting = registeredUsers.includes(username, 0);

  if (isExisting == true) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

checkName();
```

You can also `return isExisting` directly.